# Opentelemetry collector- skips histogram metric

Tags: prometheus

I am using an Opentelemetry collector. And have a prometheus receiver in it's config to scrape envoy prometheus metrics.
One metric of type histogram (envoy_cluster_external_upstream_rq_time_sum) is not getting sent by Otlp exporter. Any suggestions?

Comment: And this metric is present on the `/metrics` page?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @markalex. Yes it is. I think the issue might be with otlp exporter since I can see envoy_cluster_external_upstream_rq_time in collector logs. I have updated the question.

Comment: I can't say I fully understand you. Is this metric seen on the page that is scraped by Prometheus? Because if yes - then it should be in Prometheus. Only possible chanse of this not being the case is if Prometheus drops it on scrape (because it was configured to do it): check relabeling configs.